# How can i Limit Trafic Speed On my linux VPN Server - ( x -ui Server )

Tags: performance, user-controls, vpn, download-speed

i am using v2ray x-ui panel for my vpn server.

one port have only one user
thinking about  Apply MAX Download / Upload speed

on every port .

how can i do that .